Installing CGAL using conan.io
I would like to install CGAL using conan.io
Here is my conan file
conanfile.txt
[requires]
cgal/5.6.1
[generators]
CMakeDeps
CMakeToolchain
[layout]
cmake_layout

CMakeLists.txt
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.29)
project(example)

find_package(CGAL REQUIRED)

add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} src/hull.cpp)
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} CGAL::CGAL )

A small example program taken from here:
src/hull.cpp
#include <CGAL/Exact_predicates_inexact_constructions_kernel.h>
#include <CGAL/partition_2.h>
#include <CGAL/Partition_traits_2.h>
#include <CGAL/property_map.h>
#include <vector>
#include <cassert>
#include <list>
typedef CGAL::Exact_predicates_inexact_constructions_kernel K;
typedef CGAL::Partition_traits_2<K, CGAL::Pointer_property_map<K::Point_2>::type > Partition_traits_2;
typedef Partition_traits_2::Point_2                         Point_2;
typedef Partition_traits_2::Polygon_2                       Polygon_2;  // a polygon of indices
typedef std::list<Polygon_2>                                Polygon_list;
/*
      v4     v2
      | \   /|
      |  \ / |
      |  v3  |
      |      |
      v0-----v1
 */
int main( )
{
  std::vector<K::Point_2> points = { K::Point_2(0,0), K::Point_2(2,0), K::Point_2(2,2), K::Point_2(1,1), K::Point_2(0,2) };
  Partition_traits_2 traits(CGAL::make_property_map(points));
  Polygon_2 polygon;
  polygon.push_back(0);
  polygon.push_back(1);
  polygon.push_back(2);
  polygon.push_back(3);
  polygon.push_back(4);
  Polygon_list partition_polys;
  CGAL::y_monotone_partition_2(polygon.vertices_begin(),
                               polygon.vertices_end(),
                               std::back_inserter(partition_polys),
                               traits);
   for (const Polygon_2& poly : partition_polys){
     for(Point_2 p : poly.container()){
        std::cout << "points[" << p << "] =  " << points[p] << ", ";
      }
     std::cout << std::endl;
   }
   assert(CGAL::partition_is_valid_2(polygon.vertices_begin(),
                                     polygon.vertices_end(),
                                     partition_polys.begin(),
                                     partition_polys.end(),
                                     traits));
   return 0;
}

Attempting to build it all from the command line:
conan install . --output-folder=build --build=missing
Here is the error I get:
Error Message


I'm not wedded to MSVC or windows

The problem in Windows/MSVC for the boost package is that its build system b2 was broken with the latest VS 17.10 update. Yesterday there was a new b2/5.2.0 release that solves this issue, and the boost package in ConanCenter will be getting an update to use that latest b2/5.2.0 soon. I think that was the reason, and also why it works on Linux but failing on Windows/MSVC. I think it should be solved soon when the boost package is updated in ConanCenter

The github issue tracker in https://github.com/conan-io/conan/issues can also be used for these kind of questions, is good for official support from the maintainers.

@drodri https://github.com/conan-io/conan/issues/16492

Here's what I've come up with using docker
Dockerfile
FROM ubuntu:22.04 AS base

RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get upgrade -y
RUN apt-get install python3-venv python3-pip cmake -y
RUN python3 -m venv /venv
RUN chmod -R 777 /venv
ENV PATH="/venv/bin:$PATH"

RUN pip install conan && conan profile detect
RUN mkdir /app

docker-compose.yml
version: '3.9'
services:
  cgal:
    build: .
    volumes:
      - .:/app
    command: >
      sh -c "./venv/bin/activate && 
      conan install /app --output-folder=/app/build --build=missing && 
      cd /app/build/build/Release/generators/ &&
      cmake /app -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE="/app/build/build/Release/generators/conan_toolchain.cmake" -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE="Release" &&
      cmake --build . --config Release &&
      /app/build/build/Release/generators/example"
      
      

Run using
docker compose up
And it builds and runs

